# Why var with private setter is invariant position?

Tags: types, kotlin, covariance

(I use kotlin 1.1.2-2)

I found there are 2 ways to define property that is variable but cannot be assigned through `=`.

1. `var` with private setter
2. `val` with private variable backing property

I also found they have different behaviour.

When `T` is declared `out`, `var` of type `T` with private setter cannot be defined while `val` with backing property is legitimate.

```
open class A<out T>(v: T) {
    // error because T occurs in invariant position
    var prop1: T = v
    private set

    private var _prop: T = v
    val prop2: T get() = _prop
}
```

Why `prop1` is invariant position and `prop2` is not? Where does the difference come from?

Comment: The longer I look, the more it looks like a bug to me :/

Comment: Try to add "private get" for the prop1 variable and check again. The "private set" maybe could add an incosistent object which will be returned outside of the class.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you declare the `private var` can works is that you can't change it out of the class `A` since it is `private`, and you can't declare a function with a `out variance` parameter for the modification purpose.

The different between `private var` and `private set` is a `private` variable don't has getter/setter just generated a field in java. but `private set` properties have getter/setter and the setter is `private`.

The `out` variance is only for the read-mode, which means you can't add anything in it. and its actually type is a subtype of `T`, or `? extends T` in java.

For the write-mode of the `out` variance is equivalent to `Nothing`, so you can't declare the `setter`/mutable variable at all. but you can reference it with an immutable property, for example:

```
open class A<out T>(v: T) {
 //v--- immutable
  val prop1: T = v

}
```

If you can do it, the kotin generic is a bad thing. why? by definition,`out T` is a subtype of `T`, but you attempt to assign a supertype instance `T` to a subtype of `? extends T`, for example:

```
val subInt:A<Int> = A(1);
//             v--- Int
subInt.prop1 = 1;  // you try to assign an Int to its subtype
//     ^--- prop1 is a subtype of Int
```

Maybe the following example will makes you more clearly why can't adding anything into a `out` variance parameter.

```
val int: A<Int> = A(1) // ok

val number: A<Number> = int; //ok

number._prop = 1.0; 
//     ^
//if you can define setter/mutable variable, you try to assign a Double into a Int
```

Comment: Not having a getter/setter seems a minor implementation detail, not enough to explain the differens in type system semantics

Comment: @voddan yes, sir. Indeed, this behavior `private var prop:T = v` should be prohibited in kotlin.

Comment: There is no need to prohibit it. Kotlin is aware that allowing `private var prop: T` where `T` is a covariant (`out`) type parameter may lead to type system violation, so these properties are treated as "private to this", e.g. a class is allowed to change them only on its own instance.

Comment: @RomanElizarov hi, as you said it can changed in its own instance, so the behavior should be prohibited. let's say you have a function that you can change it internally, for example: `_prop = 1 as T`, the code is unreliable if the `T` is not a `Int`.

Comment: Can you, please, provide a self-contained example that demonstrates type system violation because of mutable properties with covariant type?

Comment: @RomanElizarov `class A<out T>(v: T) {
    private var _prop: T = v
    val prop2: T get() = _prop

    fun violated() = let { _prop = 1 as T }
}`  here is a minimum example that violate the *out* variance, and it can be compiled.

Comment: The example above has unchecked cast in `1 as T` statement, so a violation of type-safety is expected. Can you produce an example that compiles w/o warnings (and does not use reflection), yet violates type-system?

Comment: @RomanElizarov hi, there is no way to avoiding unchecked warning here, because it attempt to cast value to a generic type. and a warning doesn't violate anything, it is just a warning.and you can suppress the warning.

Comment: The code with unchecked warning is not guaranteed to be type-safe in Kotlin (and neither in Java, for that matter). You don't need to play with variance to demonstrate that compile-time type-safety can be violated if you have unchecked warning in your code.

Comment: @RomanElizarov hi, as you said **not guarateed** is well. And this warning can't be avoid, but you must use it many times in your development. If you say stop to warnings, you also say stop to development. It doesn't make sence. I'm on mobile, you can find why & when on stackoverflow.